# How to read/output response from the HTTP request

Tags: c#, http

I send HTTP request to a webpage to insert or retrieve data.

This is my code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response =  client.PostAsync(
        "url",
         new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}

DisplayAlert("Alert", json, "OK");
DisplayAlert("test", response, "test");
```

For this particular example; the website should return true or false.

But I want to read the response variable.

The `DisplayAlert("test", response, "test");` show error. And this is because I am trying to read response outside of scope.

My question is how to read the response variable or output response variable on the page?

**Edit**

```
{
    LoginModel user = new LoginModel();
    {
        user.email = email.Text;
        user.password = password.Text;

    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {


    }

    var response = client.PostAsync(
        "https://scs.agsigns.co.uk/tasks/photoapi/login-photoapi/login-check.php",
         new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));


    DisplayAlert("Alert", json, "OK");
     DisplayAlert("test", response, "test");

}
```

Comment: Move `response` outside of `using`. `HttpResponseMessage response; using(var client ...){}`. Another thing is, you are not awaiting your `PostAsnyc()` call which will led to response being of type `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

Comment: If I move response outside; Than I get red line under "client". See Edit original question

Comment: You should only move the declaration of `response` outside of the using. The `client.PostAsync()` call should stay inside of the using.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you an error because you try to access a variable which is declared inside of a different scope. If you move the variable `response` inside of the "method scope" the error will disappear:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

HttpResponseMessage response;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    response = await client.PostAsync(
        "url",
         new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}

DisplayAlert("Alert", json, "OK");
DisplayAlert("test", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), "test");
```

Note the `await` which I added just before `client.PostAsync()` (You will find more infos about async/await in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)).

To get the string representation of the response content you can use following method:

```
await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This will read the response content as string.

Comment: Thanks, @croxy. Still getting response conversion to string error.   " Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'string'"

Answer (score 0):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
HttpResponseMessage response;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    response = client.PostAsync(
        "url",
         new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json").Result);
}
var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
DisplayAlert("Alert", json, "OK");
DisplayAlert("test", body, "test");
```

should  work, by moving the declaration  of the  variable  outside the scope,  and updating the value inside the call.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it worked. Just threw another error  -  " cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' to 'string'"...I believe I need to convert this into string; not sure what would be best practice to do so.

Comment: Thanks, @Crowxy and A Ghanima for all your help. I can see the response now. Thanks